# Does pine script allow me to work with multiple time frames?

Tags: pine-script

I am a noob and want to code some fairly basic strategies for backtesting.  I want to use certain data from a daily chart to trigger a setup, so firstly I would inspect the daily data and make comparisons at the daily level.  I would also like to know how often the setup occurs.  Then, I would like to use a lower timeframe to code entry conditions for the strategy tester.

Does pinescript allow me to use different timeframes in one piece of code?  Everything I have read so far refers to "applying code to a chart" and a chart can only have one timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function to switch the symbol or resoulution.

Example (from the user manual):

```
s = security("MSFT", "D", close) // 1 Day
plot(s)

expr = sma(close, 10)
s1 = security("AAPL", "240", expr) // 240 Minutes
plot(s1)
```

I would also suggest you read [this](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/) beautiful piece of *FAQ* page written by pine developers. Search for *security* and read the questions releated to it because using the `security()` function can be tricky and pain sometimes.